# is there any way to make Text and Underline different colors in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

Is there any way to make Text color in white while underline is in yellow?

RichText, TextSpan or Text seem like don't have opportunity to do this.

this what i'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use decorationColor: yourColor inside your Text attribute to change the underline's color. For example, if you want to underline all of your text:

```
Text("Your text",
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
          decorationColor: Colors.yellow,
      ))
```

In case you want to underline only a part of text you have to use RichText with TextSpan. For example:

```
RichText(
   text: TextSpan(
   children: [
       TextSpan(
          text: "NOT UNDERLINED TEXT",
          style: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white
          )
       ),
       TextSpan(
          text: "UNDERLINED TEXT",
          style: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white,
             decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
             decorationThickness: 2,
             decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy
          )
       )
  ], 
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow)
))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Meanwhile, can I do something to force underline position a bit of the text? 
I tried to follow, but none of this worked for me
https://jtmuller5-98869.medium.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-underlining-text-in-flutter-57936f5c79bb

Comment: In that case you have to use RichText to underline only a part of the text. I've edited the answer with the solution

Comment: This is now even more useful since Material 3 is activated by default starting from Flutter 3.16; the decoration color no longer defaults to the text color

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this behaviour with a [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html).

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'You should only use this app when it is safe and legal to do so. ',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Please read our ',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Privacy Policy',
            style: TextStyle(
              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              decorationColor: Colors.yellow,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use the `Material` widget and within it you define a `RichText`, `TextSpan` and a `Text`.

Inside the `Material` widget you need to set underline color.

```
Material(
 child:RichText(),//input our need
);
```